# JMX connection to Tomcat running on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat, java, jmx

My Tomcat 7 process, which I run on a server on Amazon EC2, has settings such as these in `CATALINA_OPTS` which *should* allow me to connect for JMX monitoring remotely:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

However, **connecting remotely does not work with either jconsole or jvisualvm**. It just times out.

I've triple-checked that the EC2 security group allows access to the JMX remote port from my IP (and only from my IP).

Are there any settings missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the **java.rmi.server.hostname** option too, so that it points to the **public DNS name** of your EC2 server:

`-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=your.public.dns`

That was sufficient to get it working for me, but for more tips, try this blog post:
[JMX Monitoring on Amazon EC2](http://asaclue.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/jmx-monitoring-on-amazon-ec2/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is more complete explanation of how to do it without messing with the group security (aka firewall):

### Server side:

1. download http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.23/bin/extras/catalina-jmx-remote.jar and put it in tomcat/lib
2. add following listener to server.xml:

   > ```
   > <listener classname="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener"
   >     rmiregistryportplatform="10001" 
   >     rmiserverportplatform="10002" 
   >     uselocalports="true" />
   > ```
3. add following settings in tomcat/bin/setenv.sh:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
export CATALINA_OPTS
```

**Restart tomcat**

### Client side:

1. download same catalina-jmx-remote.jar and put it in JDK/JRE/lib/ext (same file as downloaded at Server step 1)
2. start ssh tunnel with:

   > ssh user@aws-host -L10001:127.0.0.1:10001 -L10002:127.0.0.1:10002
3. Start JConsole and enter the following remote service URL:

   > service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1:10002/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:10001/jmxrmi

**You have JConsole connected over SSH to your tomcat running on AWS.**

As posted on: http://www.cod.ro/2012/08/monitoring-tomcat-7-on-rhel-aws-using.html

Answer (score 3):

If you're having trouble setting the correct hostname for `java.rmi.server.hostname` try the following:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$(/usr/bin/curl -s --connect-timeout 2 instance-data.ec2.internal/latest/meta-data/public-hostname)
```

This is convenient to use in an Elastic Beanstalk environment where instances will come and go.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried using the JmxRemoteLifecycleListener and it didn't work for me.

This is what it worked for me:

1. I choose 1005 as JMX port and my `setenve.sh` is like:

   ```
   CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10005 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
   ```
2. Redirect using SSH the JMX port and the RMI
3. Run visualvm using the following URI:

   ```
   service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:10005/jmxrmi
   ```

If you need more information have a look to this post:
http://ignaciosuay.com/how-to-connect-a-java-profiler-like-visualvm-or-jconsole-to-a-remote-tomcat-running-on-amazon-ec2/